# weirdness with resources in WEB-INF

Tags: java, grails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I'm trying to use GetResource to reference a file packaged in the war as part of my grails app using :

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource)
```

The strange thing is it works on Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat 7 32 bit) if I build it using "grails test war" on OSX. But when it's built and deployed by the CI Server (TeamCity running on a Linux EC2 instance) with the same command, the resource is never found.

I've seen a lot of articles talking about how some environments won't unpack the war, but I don't think thats the issue because these are two different wars being sent to the SAME environment. One war works, the other doesn't

Things I've checked:
1) The war files are pretty much the same size and both have the files in WEB-INF
2) The versions of Java are similar on both machines (JDK 1.6)
3) I'm using the same version of grails on both (2.0.4)
4) I'm using the same command on both (grails test war)
5) The code is the same (both coming from the same git repo)

Any thoughts? I've read that I could use GetResourceAsStream but I'm using an email plugin that replies on physical files. I could write the stream out to a file each time but that's not much of an options.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Grails have a bean for that, called `grailsResourceLocator`. This will works in both dev and deployed environments. Example:

```
package com.mrhaki.templates

import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

class MessageService {

    def grailsResourceLocator

    String template

    String followUpMessage(final String user, final String subject) {
        final Resource template = grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI(template)
        final Map binding = [user: user, subject: subject]
        final SimpleTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
        templateEngine.createTemplate(template.URL).make(binding)
    }
}
```

This example was taken from [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/grails-goodness-accessing-resources.html).